# Store SQL query as a variable with a CGI Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I'm a newbie to python and cgi.

How do I store an SQL query as a python variable in a cgi script?

Currently, my script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#enable debugging - BEGIN
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
#enable debugging - END
#HTTP Headers - BEGIN
#set encoding to UTF-8
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()
#HTTP Headers - END
#HTML Content - BEGIN
print("<h1>Form Test</h1>")
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
username = data['username'].value
print("<p><b>Hello, " + username + "</b></p>")

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/user/BankingApp.db')
c = conn.cursor()
#Display SUM of Balances:
print ("<h1>Bank's Total Balance</h1><br />")
for row in c.execute('SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM Accounts')
 print ("Bank's Balance: $")
 print (row)
```

It produces the output:

> Bank's Balance: $ (10000.0,)

I want to print out the SUM without the parenthesis so that it reads like:

> Bank's Balance: $ 10000.0

I figure if I can store the SUM query into a variable, I can format the output however I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regular expression to remove the parenthesis and comma.

```
In [7]: import re

In [8]: x = '(10000.0,) '

In [9]: re.sub(r'[(|)|,]', '', x)
Out[9]: '10000.0 '
```